# Create Modal from document fragment

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, canjs

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var modal = $(can.view("widgetModalCtrl", {}));
$("body").append(modal);
modal.modal();
```

The can.view call returns a document fragment.  The modal call doesn't build the modal in the same way and some of the classes don't get attached to the correct dom elements on the page.  Any idea why this would be?  I can't seem to figure out why a document fragment can't function like a normal fragment of html turned into a jquery object.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more explanation or at least a fiddle showing the problem.  I'm not sure why this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works:

```
var $modal = $(can.view("widgetModalCtrl", {})).children();
$("body").append($modal);
$modal.modal();
```

I don't think I really described the problem well above.  I was trying to call the bootstrap .modal() directly on the document fragment that is returned, but you get to get .children() in order to do that.